# Is there an App-V / Docker equivalent for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, docker, appv

[Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) has a [application-virtualisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization) tool called [App-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V).

[Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) appears to have a similar tool called [Docker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29).

My question is - **is there a Docker equivalent for [MacOS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X)?** (ie without having to spin up a Linux virtual machine on VirtualBox?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no strict analog for OS X. If you are against spinning up a virtual Linux machine, your options are:

1. A simple [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) jail. The [jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) utility can help you out with this.
2. For your own OS X applications, using [App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1) to limit the resources your app has access to.

Again, neither of these is just like Docker 0.x, which uses [LXC](http://linuxcontainers.org/) under the covers.

The chroot solution is closer, since it is one of the components that LXC is built on. However, it doesn't provide kernel namespaces or anything like [cgroups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups) — both of which are two very important parts of LXC.